# Using the Facebook Graph API how can find the most liked photo in an album on one of my pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook Graph API how can find the most liked photo in an album on one of my pages?

I have access to the page insights if that can be used.

There are 200 photos in each album so I don't want to do an api request for each photo.

Answer (score 1):

Subsequently you may also find the most commented on.

Here is the code you request:

http://fivespot.me/fblikes.php

`$likes = $facebook->api('/'.$picId.'/likes');`

However if you are looking to just find out the most liked there is an app already compiled that will do this for you:

http://apps.facebook.com/imanpic/

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API doesnt support querying for an arbitrary set of photos with some criteria. BUT - you can access the Likes object for each Album, which returns a data set representing all the Liked Photos in that Album. You could then just walk that data set and count the number of times you see the same photo Like.

Thus - you just need to issue a Graph API call for Likes sub-object of an Album.

See "Likes" under "Connections" at:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

Comment: This only returns people who like the album not the individual photos.